# How do I modify the node startup command in Open Shift?

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using ES6 with babel-node to create my app and I require my app to start with the command `babel-node app.js`. This command is listed in scripts: start in my package.json so the command npm start runs the correct command.

Open shift starts node apps with node + what ever script is set in the main property of your package.json file. In my case its `"main": "app.js"`. So this command is run `node app.js`.

The server is choking on the first ES6 it encounters which makes sense. I can't figure out how to configure openshift to run `babel-node` or npm start to start up my app.

Here is my package.json file -> https://gist.github.com/jkinman/2cc57ce5fae5817d6bca

Comment: used this great yeoman generator to setup my project https://github.com/ghaiklor/generator-sails-rest-api

Comment: you might want to include that in your question since comments disappear more easily than questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't run your server with `babel-node`, which is memory intensive and not meant for production. Instead, you should use the [require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) by creating a file `start.js` (name unimportant) with the following content:

```
require('babel-core/register')
require('./app.js')
// or server.js or whatever you use to normally start you app
```

Then you can start your server with `node start.js`.