# Deploy React.js Starter Kit on Openshift

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, openshift, starter-kits

I'm trying to deploy the Starter Kit of React.js (available here : https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) on Openshift. To do that, I modified some little things that I explain here.

First, the logs in Openshift tells me that the `import` keyword in the *servers.js* file is not recognized. I think Babel is not used by Openshift at this point.

A workaround for that is mentioned here : [How do I modify the node startup command in Open Shift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636804/how-do-i-modify-the-node-startup-command-in-open-shift)

So I modified the *server.js* content (because Openshift run the `node server.js` command and not the `babel-node tools/run start` defined in the `scripts.start` property of `package.json`) with the recommended content and renamed my base `server.js` to `app.js`.

Now, the logs tells me that `babel-core` is not found so I modified the *package.json* file to put `babel-core` and `babel-cli` in `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies` and remove a `DEV` value of another property.

All the times, when I push my code on Openshift (code of the `src` folder), the compilation failed at a random time (when dependencies are installed) and it take a long long time. However, when I reboot the cartridge I can see logs I explained.

My current situation is that things are looking better but the problem is the disk space : not enough. That's surprising me because the cartridge can host 1GB and on my local machine all files with dependencies take ~148MB. I tried to delete and recreate the cartridge : the same thing appears.

Does anybody know what can be wrong here ? The fact that the cardridge exceed 1GB is weird...

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution... I hope it will save hours for some people !

- Set the "production" mode to the cartridge app (so that in don't download so many inodes) :

  `rhc set-env NODE_ENV=production --app appname`
- Don't forget to modify `config.js` :

  `export const port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || 3000;
  export const host = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 'localhost';
  export const databaseUrl = 'sqlite:' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + 'database.sqlite';`
- Modify `app.js` (include the host):

  `` import { port, host, auth, analytics } from './config';
  //...
  models.sync().catch(err => console.error(err.stack)).then(() => {
          app.listen(port, host, () => {
          console.log(`The server is running at http://${host}:${port}/`);
      }); ``